# How to convert data from object to string in mule 4?

Tags: mule, converters

I used to convert payload to string whenever i need to log the payload on console using the syntax in mule 3 [message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)] and some times used to use object to string converter or object to array converter.

But in mule 4 i don't see any converter as in mule 3 and [message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)] is alos not working.

Please assist me any new syntax of component or consept has come in mule 4  ?

**Input**

```
[
        {
            "firstName": "Ram",
            "lastName": "Ram1",
            "address": [
                {
                    "street": "a",
                    "city": "b",
                    "state": "c"
                },
                {
                    "street": "a1",
                    "city": "b1",
                    "state": "c1"
                }
            ]
        }
```

**Batch Image**
[image]

**Code**

```
        <batch:job jobName="Batch_ProcessingBatch_Job" doc:id="2582eccb-720f-499f-99fe-424cab3c9a33" >
            <batch:process-records >
                <batch:step name="Batch_Step1" doc:id="cb045f6b-edd3-426f-8f28-0d20b301fb6d" >
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="2491184f-e8d7-47b7-bef0-29bafd43247f" message="In Batch_step1........... #[payload]"/>
                    <batch:aggregator doc:name="Batch Aggregator" doc:id="aa9c1b60-395f-4376-804d-bced200dfb43" size="2">
                        <set-payload value='#[write(payload, "application/json")]' doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="9d4b27ee-5692-4a99-a93e-bd7c694f398d" />
                        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="06064422-1352-4ff9-8817-3e87eb1f4264" >
                            <ee:message >
                                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map(item,index) -> {
    name: item.firstName,
    surname: item.lastName 
}]]></ee:set-payload>
                            </ee:message>
                        </ee:transform>
                        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="c955490e-fab1-436e-8265-f706a577c9d2" message="In Batch_step1 Aggrigator........... #[payload]" />
                    </batch:aggregator>
                </batch:step>
            </batch:process-records>
            <batch:on-complete >
                <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="a3923c90-557b-4955-9c40-afd748719abd" message="#['#####It is oncomplete result####': write(payload, &quot;application/json&quot;)]"/>
            </batch:on-complete>
        </batch:job>
```

**Getting Error**

```
Message               : "You called the function 'map' with these arguments: 
  1: String ("[\n  \"{\\n  \\\"firstName\\\": \\\"Ram\\\",\\n  \\\"lastName\\\": \\\"Ram1\...)
  2: Function ((item:Any, index:Any) -> ???)

But it expects arguments of these types:
  1: Array
  2: Function


4| payload map(item,index) -> {
 |  ...
7| }

Trace:
  at map (line: 4, column: 1)
  at main (line: 4, column: 9)" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map(item,index) -> {
    name: item.firstName,
    surname: item.lastName 
}".
Error type            : MULE:EXPRESSION
Element               : Batch_ProcessingFlow/processors/0/route/0/route/0/aggregator/processors/1 @ training-1:Batch Processing.xml:27 (Transform Message)
Element XML           : <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="06064422-1352-4ff9-8817-3e87eb1f4264">
<ee:message>
<ee:set-payload>%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map(item,index) -> {
    name: item.firstName,
    surname: item.lastName 
}</ee:set-payload>
</ee:message>
</ee:transform>

  (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

Comment: updated answer per the new question.

Answer (score 0):

After quick googling the new way is to use `#[message.payload as String]` as shown in [link](https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/99393/messagepayloadasjavalangstring-in-mule-4.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `payload.^raw` syntax for the loggers. It was introduced in mule 4 and can handles cases where string conversion is needed. Typically pairs well with `output text/plain` format in a logger.

Ref: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-cookbook-extract-data#metadata_selector

*NOTE its never a good idea to log entire payloads (that could contain PII etc..) with maybe an exception where you are building a report that you need to log at the end of your batch process which possibly could be the case here...*